# how to concatenate multiple strings with commas if there is the same array data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have the array data as drawn
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRkXW.jpg)

and I want to display data like this

```
0 = "16-11-1996 / IGD"
01 = "CBC", "DIFF"
04 = "GLUS "," UR "," CRE "
```

I tried to use this [PHP splitting arrays into groups based on equal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495206/php-splitting-arrays-into-groups-based-on-equal-values/17495268) method but it was not what I expected.

i am just learning coding and i am not what way or what keywords should i use to find a solution. i hope someone can help me,

Comment: can you please copy the picture into a codeblock for ease of reading and copying for those that may want to help?

Comment: Also, what's the issue? "Not what I expected" doesn't help.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not clear, I will correct my question again. I've got the answer to my question. and @jspit's answer is the same as the script I used. thanks

Comment: which part can I mark when my question is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution that uses foreach to create a new array.

Input:

```
$data = [
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"16-11-1996 / IGD", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"0"],
    
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"CBC", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"01"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"DIFF", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"01"],

    ["OTHER_ID"=>"GLUS", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"04"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"UR", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"04"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"CRE", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"04"],
];
```

Create a array grouped by "SPEC_TYPE".

```
$arr = [];
foreach($data as $row){
  $key = $row["SPEC_TYPE"];
  $arr[$key][] = $row["OTHER_ID"];
}
```

The array has "SPEC_TYPE" as a key and all "OTHER_ID" in a subarray. With another foreach we can now do the output. We cleverly use the implode function for this.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $others){
  echo $key.' = "'.implode('", "',$others).'"<br>';
}
```

Output for the example data above:

```
0 = "16-11-1996 / IGD"
01 = "CBC", "DIFF"
04 = "GLUS", "UR", "CRE"
```

[Here you can try it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a7c363b87c294a79730ef45b3467afda23c17db0).

Comment: sorry i was late updating my question. Thank you @jspit for your help, I can solve this problem. and thanks for this script I can use it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I kept it as simple as I could since you are a beginner. First we take the unique spec types by using `array_map` to take out only spec types and then `array_unique` for taking out the unique values. After that for every spec id we would want to search the matching spec types and filter them out. For this we use `array_filter` and then again another `array_map` to take out the other ids and finally an `implode` function for converting the array into a string.

```php
$data = [
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"A", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"1"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"B", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"2"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"C", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"1"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"D", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"3"],
    ["OTHER_ID"=>"E", "SPEC_TYPE"=>"3"]
];

$result = array_map(function ($a) { return $a["SPEC_TYPE"]; }, $data);
$result = array_unique($result);

$response=[];
foreach($result as $r) {
   $response[$r] = array_filter($data, function ($d) use($r) { return $r==$d["SPEC_TYPE"]; }); 

   $response[$r] = implode(array_map(function ($a) { return $a["OTHER_ID"]; }, $response[$r]), ", ");
}

echo json_encode($response);
// {"1":"A, C","2":"B","3":"D, E"};
```

In laravel you have helper functions to reduce the unnecessary code so we can reduce our `array_map` with `array_pluck`. Also `array_where` could be used in place of `array_filter` but in this case it would have the same callback and functionality so let's keep the filter for now. Below code isn't tested but should do the thing.

```
$result = array_pluck($data, "SPEC_TYPE");
$result = array_unique($result);

$response=[];
foreach($result as $r) {
  $response[$r] = array_filter($data, function ($d) use($r) { return $r==$d["SPEC_TYPE"]; }); 
  
  $response[$r] = implode(array_pluck($response[$r], "OTHER_ID"), ", ");
}
```

Resources to study more on this:
Laravel helper functions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/helpers
PHP array functions: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp

Comment: sorry i was late updating my question.I can solve this problem. Thank you @Beshambher for your help.